# Card.ly social identity manager alternatives?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a better social identity manager than Card.ly?

It seems buggy (some errors because GD library is missing in PHP).

Answer (score 1):

I've tried [about.me](http://about.me/) and [flavors.me](http://flavors.me/) which are both simple and beautiful.